# Deleting jobs from oozie's web UI?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Oozie will be listing all the submitted job in its web UI including RUNNING, KILLED, PREP etc.  
Is there any way to delete jobs from oozie's web UI without editing metastore DB directly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are properties for removing completed job / coordinators / bundles after a set number of days has expired:

- http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/oozie-default.xml

  - `oozie.services` - Will need to contain the purge service: `org.apache.oozie.service.PurgeService`
  - `oozie.service.PurgeService.older.than` - age off completed workflows, in days
  - `oozie.service.PurgeService.coord.older.than` - age off completed coordinators, in days

There are some other related properties (`oozie.service.PurgeService.` prefixed) as to how many can be purged at once, and how often the service performs purge checking etc

As for arbitrarily removing workflows, i don't think this functionality exists.

Comment: Is there any limit on number of jobs for logs in jobtracker UI. I had executed three workflow jobs which contains 10-15 actions each and after execution i can see only last 5 jobs. I can view all but when try to search by jobid i can only search last 5 jobs.

Comment: Thank you Chris ! This Post is definitely useful.Is there any CLI for purging killed Jobs from UI.I could not see any in documentation.Scenario is I have 20 pages of killed jobs in  Web Console . I want to clear all those jobs. Thanks in advance !